# Grails/GORM Employee Salary

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm new to Grails and I'm trying to develop a web app. I was making pretty decent progress until I ran into an issue with adding a new employee with new salary. I have a Person domain class, an Employee domain class, and a Salary domain class. All of them are listed below.

```
class Person {
 String firstName, lastName
 String email
 String phoneNumber
 Employer employer 

 }

class Employee extends Person {
 Date birthdate
 JobTitle jobTitle 

 static hasMany = [salary: Salary]

}

class Salary {
 Employee employee
 double salary
 Date from_date
 Date to_date
```

Now when I create a new employee, I can't add in a new salary just for that person, only for the employees that are already in the DB. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your code, I can presume that `Salary` should contain a `Person`'s identifier, instead of `Employee`.

```
class Salary {
  Person person
  double salary
  Date from_date
  Date to_date
}
```

On the other hand, if you want `Employee` to be in the relationship with `Salary`, then the `hasMany` property should be:

```
class Person {
  String firstName, lastName
  String email
  String phoneNumber
  Employer employer 

}

class Employee extends Person {
  Date birthdate
  JobTitle jobTitle 

  static hasMany = [salary: Salary]
}

class Salary {
 Employee employee
 double salary
 Date from_date
 Date to_date
}
```

Keep in mind that these changes will affect your DB. I recommend taking a look at [DB Migration](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration).